# как из массива числа вывести в строчку

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

```
import random

n=5
нормальные=[]

for нормальные in range(n):
    t=random.randint(-5,10)
    print(t)
```

выводит 5 чисел

-5
10
3
5
7

мне нужно: -5 10 3 5 7

ps: извиняюсь за оформление новичок на сайте

Comment: почитайте про print: `print(t, end=' ')`

Comment: фактически в коде вы выводите числа не из массива, а просто печатаете новое значение в цикле

Answer (score 1):

**вариант 1:** сначала накопить данные, затем вывести

```
print(*[random.randint(-5,10) for i in range(n)])
```

**вариант 2:** переопределить завершение строки вместо `'\n'` на `' '`

```
for i in range(n):
    t=random.randint(-5,10)
    print(t, end=' ')
```